# Agile Web Development w/ Rails (4th e) Cart Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, functional-testing, cart, nomethoderror

I'm working through Agile Web Dev w/ Rails book (4th ed) and I'm totally stuck...
I'm running Rails 3.2.3 on Mac OSX.
Im on **task D-3: Adding a Button**.... it started with the test:functionals not working at the end of the chapter... it gave me an error saying:

```
Can't Mass assign protected attributes: product
```

I followed the advice given here: http://forums.pragprog.com/forums/148/topics/10565

and changed my line of code in the Line_Items_Controller to

```
@line_item = @cart.line_items.build
@line_item.product = product
```

Here is what my current Line_Items_Controller create method looks like:

```
# POST /line_items

def create
@cart = current_cart
product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
@line_item = @cart.line_items.build
@line_item.product = product

respond_to do |format|
  if @line_item.save
    format.html { redirect_to(@line_item.cart,
      :notice => 'Line item was successfully created.') }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @line_item,
      :status => :created, :location => @line_item }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @line_item.errors,
      :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

Now I am getting this weird message:

```
NoMethodError in LineItemsController#create undefined method `product=' for   <LineItem:0x000001024f7fb0>
```

Here is my LineItem model

```
   class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :cart_id, :product_id, :product
end
```

Im not really sure what to do at this point, since I'm a total Rails (& Ruby) newb.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Would need to see your LineItem model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the original line of code
`@line_item = @cart.line_items.build(product: product)` to `@line_item = @cart.line_items.build(:product_id => product.id)` in `line_items_controller.rb` solved this problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case there is :product_id in LineItem attr_accessible:

```
attr_accessible :cart_id, :product_id
```

So i changed :product => product in build's attributes to :product_id => product.id and it works.

```
@line_item = @cart.line_items.build(:product_id => product.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want the example from the book to work exactly the way they typed it up, go to models/line_item.rb and add attr_accessible to look like this;

```
attr_accessible :cart_id, :product_id, :product
```

n'joy.

Answer (score 0):

Your line item model doesn't have an `ActiveRecord` association for Product. I'm not sure what you're building but I assume you'll want:

```
#lineitem
belongs_to :produce

#product
has_many :line_items
```

You'll also need to add product_id to your line items table.